# __local atomic in opencl

Tags: opencl, atomic, increment

About atomic access of __local variables:

I know it's slow to do global operations compared with local ones. In this sense I'd like to make atomic access of some variables.

I know I can do atomic operations in OpenCL:

```
// Program A:
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics : enable
__kernel void test(global int * num)
{
    atom_inc(&num[0]);
}
```

How do I share atomic data between work-itens within a given work-group?

for ex: I'd like to do something like that:

```
// Program B: (it doesn't work, just to show how I'd like it to be)
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics : enable
__kernel void test(global int * num, const int numOperations)
{
    __local int num;
    if (get_global_id(0) < numOperations) {
        atom_inc(&num);
    }
}
```

In the end the num value should return: numOperations - 1;

Isn't this possible? If not how could I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically, you have one thread which intializes the shared (local) atomic followed by some barrier. I.e. your kernel starts like this:

```
__local int sharedNum;
if (get_local_id (0) == 0) {
    sharedNum = 0;
}
barrier (CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

// Now, you can use sharedNum
while (is_work_left ()) {
    atomic_inc (&sharedNum);
}
```

There's not much magic to it -- all items in a work-group can see the same local variables, so you can just access it as usual.

Comment: You need `atom_inc (&sharedNum, 1);` -- see the manual page for details: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atom_inc.html

Comment: I did just write wrongly, the right is: atom_inc (&sharedNum, 1);
BTW this doesn't work, I'm putting #pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_int64_base_atomics : enable

Comment: If it is an int, you don't need 64-bit atomics? What is the error message you get? "It doesn' work" ain't helpful.

Comment: the error is the following: error: no matching function for call to 'atom_inc' atom_inc(&sharedNum, 1);

Comment: Use the man-page: For 32-bit, it's atomic_inc: http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atomic_inc.html

Comment: Why atom_inc(ptr, 1)? I'd understand atom_add(ptr, 1), but inc is supposed to be increment, no? It knows it is supposed to "add 1".

Comment: Just fixed it, it is `atomic_inc` without the ,1. This can be potentially faster if the hardware has support for it (as it is less general than the `atomic_add` function.)